# get json data from different links and show in one activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, hyperlink

i wanna get json data from multi links and show each of them based on their id's in one activity . I also have a recyclerview when i click on one of its item the json Returns an id and this id  is relate to those json object links. so here is my question : when i click on one item i want to see the exact data's from that link which relate to the id. also this links has the same json object just their values are different....
(One thing i tried was that i moved id from the recyclerview activity to the 2nd activity and put the Id between my link to generate the link every time some one click on an item like this:

http://api.androidhive.info/volley/"+Id+"/person_object.json

of course this not the original link.)

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Hit http request using Volley or httpUrlConnection they are the same

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I already get json data from server but this is just one of them. i have plenty of urls and dont know how to show their json data in one activity

Answer (score 0):

well, just on each of them run something like

```
  try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        mMain_adapter.add(new DataObject(row.getString("title"), row.getString("desc")));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and it should be fine.
[here is](https://github.com/WithoutCaps/PHPCommunication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/site/withoutcaps/phpcommunication/MainActivity.java) a small demo app for it